# how to run two Xcode sessions connected with their own iOS simulators? (Two Xcodes, Two simulators)

Tags: xcode, ios-simulator

Currently I am converting some old obj-c project that runs only in 32bit architecture targets, to make it run on 64bit architecture targets. So I am running two Xcode sessions with different target configurations (esp target architecture) to be able to compare the intermediate results along making progress. 
However, there is one hassle regarding the simulator. Because there is only one simulator attached to two Xcode sessions, the simulator reboots whenever I switch between two Xcode sessions (i.e iPhone5 <---> iPhone6). So I am wondering how to run additional simulator that is connected to one of Xcode sessions, such that I can have two complete test setups:
(Xcode(prj-32bit) + iPhone5-simulator) and (Xcode(prj-64bit) + iPhone6-simulator).
I have googled this only to find some techniques regarding how to run multiple simulators, and those multiple simulator cannot not be connected to Xcodes independently, even though those simulators can run simultaneously.

Any answers, helpful comments are appreciated.
(I am using Xcode 8.33 by the way.)

Comment: This should work in Xcode 9. If it doesn't please file a bug and describe in detail exactly what you are trying to do so we can figure out if there is a bug or a way we can improve the workflow.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I haven't upgraded my Xcode to 9 yet and most likely will not until the current project is completed. However I will check Xcode9 and post the results as soon as I upgrade my Xcode to version 9.